# Visual Studio 2013 Issue: Installation got stuck on android SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying to install Multi-Device Hybrid Apps extension on Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate). But Installation got stuck when Android SDK being install. I have waited for 2 to 3 hours but it stuck there. I have cancelled the process and tried again but same issue.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Check the install log and see if it shows any error message. To view the log, go to %temp%, open file ending with *. _mdd_external_android_sdk.txt, example dd___20140904173812_017_mdd_external_android_sdk.txt.You can post the error message as it might help to identify the issue.

Comment: Same issue. Can not find the log file.

Comment: "go find the log file" is not helpful nor is it a solution. The problem is with the installer ... it's clunky and takes forever (2-4 hours) to run on a decent machine. And, it seems intermittent. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't -- after spending 30-48 hours trying to hunt down and clean up all the junk the installer leaves behind.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for Visual Studio 2015 RC1. The Android images take a long time to download, especially if you are downloading other things on the same network and have slow internet.

I found the AndroidSDK_SI.log file in %temp% and it shows it was actually still downloading even after 3 hours!

I believe the installer really needs to show better feedback. It seemed like the installer was hung, but it was actually downloading very slowly. Something as dirty as an option to read the currently running log file being in a text box would even help.

You can also kill the SecondaryInstaller.exe in Task Manager to stop the Android SDK sub-installer. You can then try fix it yourself or Repair Visual Studio if the install continues and completes.

Repair is available by right clicking on Visual Studio in the Microsoft Windows "Programs and Features" control panel section and clicking "Change". This will bring up a Visual Studio dialog where you can Modify or Repair the install.